# How to separate each tr of table by jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I've a table. At that table I've used something like jQuery toggle radio button. Here is my work: http://jsfiddle.net/96t7D/

My goal is that user can select only one "Y" button in a row, that's why, I've used something like radio button (but not exactly radio button, Because, I'll have to modify that button highly which can be tough with real radio button). But the problem is, only one button can be selected at the whole table now. I don't need for the whole table. I need it for each row so that user can select one "Y" button at first row, they have to select one "Y" button at second row and so on. In short, at every row, there should be a selected "Y" button by clicking from user. I need it with jQuery. Now, my script is written for the whole "Y" button. I need it will be separated by each row, so that it'll work at the row basis. But, I can't understand how can I make this script separated for each row(I don't want to use different id for every row, because there can be huge number of rows, so, it'll difficult to define all that id at the script):

```
$('.toggleButtonRadio').click(function(){
    $('.toggleButtonRadio').removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('.toggleButtonRadio').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings('td').find('.toggleButtonRadio').removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96t7D/2/)**